# Mysql get rows between date split between year and month columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a year and month in different columns, and I need to find all rows between 3 months ago and now.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-01')) >= 
          DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
```

It just seems rather verbose, and possibly inefficient as this is a very large table.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you say it's inefficient ?

Comment: How about storing dates as dates?

Comment: Yes, create a new column and store the entire date in one column. Seperating it has... no purpose.

Comment: @Dark Slipstream: It does, if the primary need is for year/month searching.  A date field requires arbitrary dates in order to use an index.

Comment: @Adel, because it take 0.5 secs with about 4,000 rows, and there will be about 1,000,000+ in production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't much optimization to be had when the date is stored as separate fields, but I would re-write your query as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`year`+ '-'+ `month` + '-01', '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

The concatenation renders indexing on the `year` and `month` columns useless.

For more info about MySQL date functions, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same issue and I have figured what I think is the solution for this case.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (month >= (month(curdate()) - 3 AND year >= year(curdate())) 
      AND (month >= month(curdate()) AND year >= year(curdate())))
```

Supposing you have columns named year and month.

Comment: And when you're doing it across a year? E.g. from November 2012 to February 2013...